# Si no hay datos en la tabla mostrar otra cosa - Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Hola no consigo hacer que si no encuentra datos me muestre lo que hay dentro del `else`. Ahora mismo he borrado lo que hacia porque no se que variable consultar para hacer el `if`

**Modelo User**

```
    protected $table = 'users';
    protected $primaryKey='id';

    public function direcciones()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Direccion', 'user_id');
    }
```

**Modelo Direccion**

```
protected $table = 'direccions';

    public function usuario()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'id');
    }
```

Comentar que un usuario puede tener muchas direcciones.

Como en la vista que estoy es la de editar un usuario extraigo la consulta así:

```
$usuario = User::with('direcciones')->find(Auth::User()->id);
```

Luego en la vista.

```
    <div class="col-12 col-md-7 col-xl-8">
        @foreach ($usuario->direcciones as $list)    
            <div class="direcciones dato_tabla">
                <h2>{{ $list->nombre }}</h2>
                <div>{{ $list->direccion }} {{ $list->numeros }}</div>
                <div>{{ $list->postal }} {{ $list->ciudad }} ({{ $list->provincia }})</div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <div class="pull-right">
                            <a href="" class="editDireccion">Editar</a>
                            <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="{{ $list->id }}" class="deleteDireccion">Eliminar</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>    
        @endforeach
    </div>
```

Lo que necesito es que si no hay resultado mostrar otra cosa, he probado con `if else` pero sin éxito, normalmente no tengo problemas con esto, no se que pasa...

Comment: intenta con `forelse`

Comment: Hola @Dohko19 que torpeza la mia, no cai en el forelse. Coloca un respuesta si quieres y la doy como valida

Comment: Si gustas respóndete a ti mismo, no puse ejemplo por q estoy desde el movil xd

Comment: Gracias @BetaM ya tenia la solución pero no tube tiempo de publicarla

Answer (score 0):

Bueno tras el consejo de Dohko19 publico la respuesta a la solución.

```
           @forelse ($usuario->direcciones as $list)
                <div class="direcciones dato_tabla">
                    <h2>{{ $list->nombre }}</h2>
                    <div>{{ $list->direccion }} {{ $list->numeros }}</div>
                    <div>{{ $list->postal }} {{ $list->ciudad }} ({{ $list->provincia }})</div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <div class="pull-right">
                                <a href="{{ route('web.direccion_Edit', $list->id) }}" class="editDireccion">Editar</a>
                                <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="{{ $list->id }}" class="deleteDireccion">Eliminar</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>    
            @empty
              <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">
                No tienes direcciones, añade una para comenzar a hacer pedidos!
              </div>
            @endforelse
```